# Make alternate letters capital

Tags: python

I want to make alternate letter capital for any given word. So I create below function. But the issue is that it doesn't return any value. Rather I feel, it goes in infinite loop.

```
def farrange(word):
finaloutput = ''
i = 0
for i in word:
    if i%2 == 0:
        finaloutput = finaloutput + word[i].upper()        
    else:            
        finaloutput = finaloutput + word[i].lower()    
    i = i + 1   
return finaloutput
```

I know there are other ways to solve the problem. I used another way of tuples unpacking. But I want to know why is it happening?

Comment: The indentation is broken. The function body has to be one level below the `def` line.

Comment: Please add expected input and output

Comment: Hint: stick `print(i)` right before your `if i%2 == 0:` line, and see what it says.

Comment: You have two `i`s (no pun intended).  One is a count and the other is a char, assuming `word` is a string.

Comment: What do you expect `i%2` yield? `i` is a character, not index.

Comment: my mistake, I was thinking it will take a number while going through the word. got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `i` as both a loop variable (incrementing integer) and a variable to hold a string. That is why it isn't working. Try this fixed code of the function:

```
finaloutput = ''
i = 0
for e in word:
    if i%2 == 0:
        finaloutput = finaloutput + e.upper()        
    else:            
        finaloutput = finaloutput + e.lower()    
    i = i + 1   
return finaloutput
```

You could also do a list comprehension:

```
''.join([e.lower() if c%2 else e.upper() for c,e in enumerate(a)])
```

Comment: Thank You for the explanation. Is it possible to use a while loop?
Say

def farrange(word):
    finaloutput = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if i%2 == 0:
            finaloutput = finaloutput + word[i].upper()        
        else:
            finaloutput = finaloutput + word[i].lower()    
    i = i + 1   
    return finaloutput
print(farrange(""))

Comment: Yeah, your while loop worked (after being properly indented)

Comment: I posted an identical solution as I didn't saw your edit. Maybe it was better to post your second solution as a different answer. The two approaches are completely different.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are iterating through the word and using its letters as indexes, this would fix it:

```
def farrange(word):
    finaloutput = ''
    for i, l in enumerate(word):
        if i%2 == 0:
            finaloutput += l.upper()        
        else:            
            finaloutput += l.lower()    
return finaloutput
```

a more pythonic way for example:

```
def arrange(word):
    op = (
        str.upper,
        str.lower
    )
    return "".join(op[x%2](l) for x, l in enumerate(word))
```

Comment: Any particular reason to make `op` a dict rather than a list?

Comment: @dashiell, no, just that i usually use dicts for convenience since they work over almost any type, but in this case a tuple seems even better

Comment: Yes, a tuple's better. And smaller. Compare `sys.getsizeof((str.upper,str.lower))` vs `sys.getsizeof({0:str.upper, 1:str.lower})`

Answer (score 2):

This is an (almost) one liner solution

```
altLttrs = lambda x :"".join([w.lower() if i%2 
                              else w.upper() 
                              for i, w in enumerate(list(x))])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-using and overriding variable `i`. Change one `i` to other variable.like:

```
def farrange(word):
    finaloutput = ''
    j = 0
    for i in word:
        if j%2 == 0:
            finaloutput = finaloutput + i.upper()
        else:
            finaloutput = finaloutput + i.lower()
        j = j + 1
    return finaloutput
print(farrange("abc"))
```

Output:

```
AbC
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you All for the explanations and shortcuts!
What if I use a while loop?

```
def farrange(word):
finaloutput = ''
i = 0
while i < len(word):
    if i%2 == 0:
        finaloutput = finaloutput + word[i].upper()        
    else:
        finaloutput = finaloutput + word[i].lower()
    i = i + 1 
return finaloutput
```

`print(farrange("abc")`

In this case, I am using i as loop variable and same value of it goes as index in a word. So I feel this should work, but this time, I get only first letter in answer. nothing else. To check if counter is not stuck in while loop, i changed while condition as `while i < 3.` But no use. It again returns output as a.

Comment: This is a new question, not an answer, so it doesn't belong here in the Answers section. If you have  new question, then ask a new question, possibly linking to this one so people know it's a follow-on question.

Comment: But anyway, it's more efficient (and more Pythonic) to use a `for` loop rather than a`while` loop, when you have a choice. And it's better to loop directly over a container's items rather than using indirect looping with indices.

Answer (score 0):

It will workout for sure ...

```
def myfunc(word):

    finaloutput = ''


    for i, l in enumerate(word):

        if i%2 == 0:

            finaloutput += l.upper()
        
        else:            

            finaloutput += l.lower() 
   
    return finaloutput

myfunc('mani')
```

Output : `MaNi`